# Conditional Multiply Two Data Frames

Tags: r, conditional-statements, product

I would like to know how I can neatly multiply two data frames based on a matching condition. For exemple:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = letters[seq(1,5)], c2 = seq(1,5), c3 = seq(31,35), c4 = seq(41,45))

df1
   c1 c2 c3 c4
1  a  1 31 41
2  b  2 32 42
3  c  3 33 43
4  d  4 34 44
5  e  5 35 45

df2 <- data.frame(c1 = letters[seq(5,1)], c2 = seq(11,15), c3 = seq(21,25), c4 = seq(1,5))

df2
   c1 c2 c3 c4
1  e 11 21  1
2  d 12 22  2
3  c 13 23  3
4  b 14 24  4
5  a 15 25  5
```

I would like to produce a third data frame as bellow:

```
df3 <- data.frame(c1 = letters[seq(1,5)], c2 = c(15,28,39,48,55), c3 = c(775,768,759,748,735), c4 = c(205,168,129,88,45))

df3
  c1 c2  c3  c4
1  a 15 775 205
2  b 28 768 168
3  c 39 759 129
4  d 48 748  88
5  e 55 735  45
```

That is, I want to match the first column (c1), which is my criteria, in the two data frames, and then multiply the corresponding elements, e.g.:  match "b" in df1 with "b" in df2 and then, for each column, multiply the corresponding elements - 2*14 = 28, for c2; 32*24 = 768, for c3; and 42*4 = 168, for c4.

Is there a clean way to do this? I haven't found it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two data frames by their first columns and then cbind the first column of the merged data frame to the required product.  Finally set the names.

```
m <- merge(df1, df2, by = 1)
mm <- cbind(m[1], m[2:4] * m[5:7])
names(mm) <- names(df1)
```

giving:

```
> mm
  c1 c2  c3  c4
1  a 15 775 205
2  b 28 768 168
3  c 39 759 129
4  d 48 748  88
5  e 55 735  45
```